# Javascript and HTML Catch Throw error returned

Tags: javascript, html

Using a website called JS Bin (https://jsbin.com) i am trying to code a quadratic formula solver and when i run my code it returns this:

```
<script>try {function solve(a, b, c) { 
var result = (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a); 
var result2 = (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a); 
return result + "<br>" + result2;
} catch (error) { throw error; }
```

here is the HTML:

```
<form> <input type="number" placeholder="A"> 
 <input type="number" placeholder="B">
 <input type="number" placeholder="C">
 <textarea rows="10" cols="60" placeholder="Your Output">
```

and here is the Javascript:

```
function solve(a, b, c) { 
var result = (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a); 
var result2 = (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a); 
return result + "<br>" + result2;
```

I tried to find an answer online but i did not find anything helpful, can anyone help me with this? i want the code to just produce the output of the javascript into the textarea.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You should just **close** **your** `<textarea>` **tag** using  `</textarea>`. Also, don't forget to **close your** `solve` **function** declaration with a curly bracket `}` at the end :

```js
function solve(a, b, c) { 

var result = (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a); 

var result2 = (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a); 

return result + "<br>" + result2; 
}
```

```html
<form> <input type="number" placeholder="A"> 
 <input type="number" placeholder="B">
 <input type="number" placeholder="C">
 <textarea rows="10" cols="60" placeholder="Your Output"></textarea>
 </form>
```